# Interpreting a simple linear regression coefficient scaled by the mean of y?

Tags: regression-coefficients

I have come across an industry example of a simple linear regression ($y=a+bx+\epsilon$) where the slope coefficient has been adjusted by the mean of $y$ ($b/\text{mean}(y)$) and described as a "slope impact".  The exact interpretation that they use is that this slope impact represents "the percentage change in $y$ for every unit above the average value of $x$".

I am not sure this interpretation is correct but would appreciate any feedback you could give on this calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct.  Think of the example where mean(y)=0.  You cannot in general use a mean like this.  If you needed a standardized impact measure (highly discouraged; reporting in real units is *much* more helpful and relevant) you almost always need the normalizing factor to be a measure of dispersion that cannot be zero unless all values are identical, for example, Gini's mean difference (mean absolute difference between any two `y`-values) or standard deviation.

By in my humble opinion the desire for unitless impact measures of the type you read about is often caused by avoidance of thinking.

Comment: Thanks for swift response.  The scary part is that this is being used in an energy demand forecast model!

Comment: Yes, and most people doing this kind of scaling don't recognize the estimation error in the thing used in scaling (here, the mean).

Comment: Frank, just to clarify, if a measure of dispersion such as the SD is used, what is the appropriate interpretation for the Beta coefficient ?

Comment: I don't like scaling on $Y$ but rather finding changes in $Y$ per meaningful changes in $X$.  We condition on $X$ anyway so computing changes in $X$ doesn't cause estimation error in the usual sense.  I like to compute inter-quartile-range effects for each $X$, i.e., keep other $X$s constant and vary one $X$ from its first to its third quartile, computing two predicted values, then subtracting one from another.  That is the default in my R `rms` package's `summary` function.

Comment: That does seem much more intuitive. Thanks i will take a detailed look at your r package.